# How should I turn a record of options into a list of strings?

Tags: haskell

I have a record of Options that I need to turn into command line arguments.

For example:

```hs
data Options = Options { optFoo :: Maybe Int
                       , optYes :: Bool
                       , optBar :: Maybe String
                       }

options = Options { optFoo = Just 3
                  , optYes = True
                  , optBar = Nothing
                  }

callThing :: Options -> IO ()
callThing opts = do
    callProcess "/usr/bin/thing" $ optsToArgs opts

-- Output should be: ["--foo", "3", "-y"]
optsToArgs :: Options -> [String]
optsToArgs opts = ???
```

I was imagining being able to use a List Monad, but I can't figure out how to make it work.

In my specific case, Options has about 20 different things in it so a solution with nested if/case statements would not be ideal.

Is there a common pattern for solving this kind of problem?

Comment: If it's "only" to use them as command line arguments, use one of the excellent libraries that already exist: https://wiki.haskell.org/Command_line_option_parsers. I've used optparse-applicative and cmdargs with success.

Comment: @JPMoresmau My scenario is in the other direction. I'm creating a library that abstracts over the command line, so a command line parser would not help in this case.

Comment: Oh sorry yes I see in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a TypeClass that takes the name of the option as a parameter.

```
class ToCommand a where
  toCmd :: a -> String -> [String]

instance ToCommand Int where
  toCmd i n = [n,show i]

instance ToCommand Bool where
  toCmd True n = [n]
  toCmd False _ = []

instance (ToCommand a)=> ToCommand (Maybe a) where
  toCmd Nothing _ = []
  toCmd (Just a) n = toCmd a n
```

And with RecordWildcards you could do

```
 optToArgs opts{..} = concat (toCmd optFoo "--foo") (toCmd optYes "-y") ...
```

Maybe a more generic solution would work, but it would be more complex to put in place.

Answer (score 5):

No, there isn't really a built-in way to do this, to my knowledge.  You could try to use some sort of generic programming, but that's likely not to work very well and be pretty difficult.  Instead, I would suggest restructuring your `Options` type:

```
data Option
    = Foo Int
    | Yes
    | Bar String
    deriving (Eq, Show)

type Options = [Option]

optToArgs :: Option -> [String]
optToArgs opt = case opt of
    Foo n -> ["--foo", show n]
    Yes   -> ["-y"]
    Bar s -> ["--bar", s]

optsToArgs :: Options -> [String]
optsToArgs = concatMap optToArgs
```

Then you would have

```
> optsToArgs [Foo 3, Yes]
["--foo", "3", "-y"]
> optsToArgs [Yes, Bar "test"]
["-y", "--bar", "test"]
```

This way you have a different constructor for each option.  The conversion from a single option to its corresponding arguments is handled in one place, then converting multiple options to the arguments list is simple.  This would also allow you to have a more hierarchical options structure if needed:

```
data FooOption
    = Foo1 Int
    | Foo2 Double

data BarOption
    = Bar1 String
    = Bar2 (String, String)

class Opt o where
    toArgs :: o -> [String]

instance Opt FooOption where
    toArgs (Foo1 n) = ["--foo", show n]
    toArgs (Foo2 d) = ["--foo", show d]

instance Opt BarOption where
    toArgs (Bar1 s) = ["--bar", s]
    toArgs (Bar2 (s1, s2)) = ["--bar", s1, "--bar", s2]

data Option
    = Foo FooOption
    | Bar BarOption
    | Yes

instance Opt Option where
    toArgs (Foo f) = toArgs f
    toArgs (Bar b) = toArgs b
    toArgs Yes     = ["-y"]

type Options = [Option]

instance Opt o => Opt [o] where
    toArgs = concatMap toArgs
```

Then you'd just have

```
callThing = callProcess "/usr/bin/thing" . toArgs
```

As an example:

```
> toArgs [Bar $ Bar2 ("hello", "world"), Foo $ Foo1 3, Yes]
["--bar", "hello", "--bar", "world", "--foo", "3", "-y"]
```

Comment: I like this solution, but unfortunately I can only pick one answer. I picked the other one because it is simpler and fits my scenario directly, though I'm going to try changing my Options type and see if I like this it better.